# What's the point of using a firewall to filter ports if they are closed by default?

Tags: firewalls, ports

I'm just learning most of this stuff so bare with me;

Using a firewall service such as iptables, is there a point in filtering/blocking a port that is not in use meaning it's closed by default?

Answer (score 0):

It does not seem to give more protection if you block access to a port which is not used anyway or is not accessible from outside because its bound to 127.0.0.1 only.

But, can you really guarantee that the port will not be used? A simple misconfiguration like a typo might be enough to make a service accessible from outside. Thus, it is preferred to have a **defense in depth**: deny with firewalls rules every access from outside except for the services which are supposed to be reachable, i.e. whitelist selected ports only. Then even a misconfiguration of a service will not make it accidentally accessible from outside.